# ADFS Authentication Error on domain MSIS7042

Tags: authentication, iis, adfs, application-pool

We are using adfs for authenticating on the domain and a adfs proxy to the internal adfs server for authenticating off of our domain. This issue does not affect users off of the domain going through the proxy.

To reproduce our issue, I opened up a VM and browsed to the URL in a private browser window and logged in, this worked fine. I browsed to the same URL in a private browser on a different machine and logged in as the same user, and I get the MSIS7042 multiple redirects error. If I log out of the site on the VM and try to log back in I get the same error.

After recycling the app pool on iis I can log back in. The same error will arise if I follow the above steps. So my issues is that the same user cannot login to the same site on the domain at the same time.

This will affect other users once ADFS gets the MSIS7042 error and no one can login until I recycle the app pool.

Comment: This info is insufficient. You need to enable logging at the token consuming app side to see why it repeatedly redirects back to AD FS. What is the app side using for consuming claims? Is it using WIF? OWIN? or something else?

Comment: it is using OWIN.

Comment: We also tried to use the .net cookie handler as well and that too did not alleviate the issue. http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System.Web%20response%20cookie%20integration%20issues&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Not a developer but all I can say is OWIN diagnostics is whats needed. https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473126 might help. See bottom of article. I also see other folk posting similar redirect experiences on SO so worth a little look here. I am an AD FS guy and unless you can show me some app side logs from OWIN or otherwise, I cant make anymore suggestions.